# Scope needs to be added to parent class of backing bean otherwise exception javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException is thrown

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces, scope

I am recently tasked with migrating an existing application (using myfaces 2 and primefaces 5) from Tomcat(JDK 1.7) to JBoss(openJDK 1.8). Ultimately, the app was able to startup and I managed to reach the login page and logged in successfully.

Once logged in, the SidebarBacking class will be called. This SidebarBacking class extends a AbstractBean class (with no scope defined) and injects a AppContextBean for the menu.

```
package com.myapp.pkg1.web.mbean.common;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SidebarBacking extends AbstractBean
{
    ....

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{appcontextbean}")
    AppContextBean appContextBean;

    public void setAppContextBean(AppContextBean appContextBean) {
        this.appContextBean = appContextBean;
    }

    public AppContextBean getAppContextBean() {
        return appContextBean;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        MenuParser.getInstance().setParentStyle("ui-state-default");
        MenuParser.getInstance().setChildStyle("ui-sidebar-menuitem-child");
        root = MenuParser.getInstance().generateMenuTree(authorities(), getAppContextBean().getMenu(),true);
    }

    ....
}
```

```
package com.myapp.pkg1.web.mbean.common;

@ManagedBean(name="appcontextbean", eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppContextBean implements Serializable
{
    ...
    private Menu menu;
    private final String menuPath = "/xml/menu.xml";

    public AppContextBean() {
        if(menu == null){
            try {
                this.menu = MenuBuilder.getInstance().loadMenuFromClassPath(menuPath);
            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                throw new SystemException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                throw new SystemException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new SystemException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
            }
        }
    }

    public Menu getMenu() {
        return menu;
    }

    public void setMenu(Menu menu) {
        this.menu = menu;
    }

    public String getMenuPath() {
        return menuPath;
    }
}
```

```
package com.myapp.pkg2.web.mbean;

public class AbstractBean implements Serializable
{
    ...

    protected FacesContext facesContext() {
        return (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
    }

    protected ExternalContext externalContext() {       
        if (facesContext() != null)
            return facesContext().getExternalContext();
        else
            return null;
    }

    protected SecurityContext securityContext(){
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    }

    protected WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext() {
        return FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(facesContext());
    }

    protected HttpServletRequest request() {
        return (HttpServletRequest) externalContext().getRequest();
    }

    protected HttpSession session() {
        return (HttpSession) externalContext().getSession(false);
    }

    protected ServletResponse response() {
        return (ServletResponse) externalContext().getResponse();
    }

    protected void forward(String uri) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request().getRequestDispatcher(uri);
        dispatcher.forward(request(), response());
    }

    protected void redirect(String uri) throws IOException {
        externalContext().redirect(uri);
    }

    protected String getRequestParameter(String key) {
        return request().getParameter(key);
    }

    protected void putSessionAttribute(String key, Object value) {
        externalContext().getSessionMap().put(key, value);
    }

    protected Object getSessionAttribute(String key) {
        return externalContext().getSessionMap().get(key);
    }

    protected Object removeSessionAttribute(String key) {
        return externalContext().getSessionMap().remove(key);
    }

    protected void addInfoMessage(String clientId, String text)
    {
        facesContext().addMessage(clientId, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, text, text));
    }

    ....
}
```

On successfully login, I am able to see the side menu and main page with all the table of data retrieved from the database.
The issue is when I click on any of the menu link, it will throw the following exceptions.

```
940 SEVERE [org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler] (default task-1) FullAjaxExceptionHandler: An exception occurred during processing JSF ajax request. Error page '/faces/pages/common/login.xhtml' will be shown.: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: /pages/inbox/myInbox.xhtmlNo saved view state could be found for the view identifier: /pages/inbox/myInbox.xhtml
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:132)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at com.myapp.pkg2.web.cache.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:40)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at com.myapp.pkg2.web.logging.LogFilter.doFilter(LogFilter.java:33)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:64)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:55)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

```
994 SEVERE [org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler] (default task-1) FullAjaxExceptionHandler: An exception occurred during rendering JSF ajax response. Error page '/faces/pages/common/errorPage.xhtml' will be shown.: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must be called before the start element is closed (attribute 'autocomplete')
    ....
```

I read that this indicates that the scope already expired when you access the page.
I am able to resolve the exception if I add a scope to the AbstractBean class, however this will cause a problem.

Whenever any data is updated, although the database is updated successfully, data across the whole website will still not be refreshed to its latest information. The data remain in the last state when they are first retrieved. Only when I logged out and logged in again, then only will the new data be reflected.

```
package com.myapp.pkg2.web.mbean;

@ManagedBean(name = "abstractBean")
@SessionScoped
public class AbstractBean implements Serializable
{
    ....
```

I also tried playing around with a few variation for p:commandButton but with no success

```
<p:commandButton id="btnAssign" value="Assign" action="#{myInbox.assignWork}" update="@all" />
<p:commandButton id="btnAssign" value="Assign" action="#{myInbox.assignWork}" update="@form" />
<p:commandButton id="btnAssign" value="Assign" action="#{myInbox.assignWork}" update="dataTable" />
<p:commandButton id="btnAssign" value="Assign" action="#{myInbox.assignWork}" update=":form:dataTable" />
<p:commandButton id="btnAssign" value="Assign" action="#{myInbox.assignWork}" process="@all" update="dataTable" />
```

The problem seem to be due to the scope that was added to the AbstractBean as all the backing beans (e.g. MyInboxBacking) extends the AbstractBean class. Therefore, even if they have their own scope (e.g. @RequestScoped, @ViewScoped), they will not take effect due to the parent class's scope.

As such, how can I remove the scope from the AbstractBean without causing the exception stated or is there any way I can refresh the data even with the @Sessionscoped?

Comment: Why do the getter and setter in `SidebarBacking` have different names? Why do you 'inject' AppContextBean in `SidebarBacking` even it's already injected in the base-class? Why don't you use `Named` and `Inject` (CDI)? I think, you should remove the `ManagedProperty` in the base class since the base class has no scope.

Comment: Hi sorry both are typo mistakes, i had corrected it! There should only be managedproperty in the sidebarbacking and not in the base class AbstractBean. The code is already using managedbean when given to me, therefore I did not use named and inject.